# hiding a link after first click in html.disable link.in html.java

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coding-style, hidden

I am passing some values through a link "Like",I want to set the property such that the link is hidden or disabled if it is clicked once..
 have tried this code
`onclick="this.style.display='none';"`

But it does not seems to be working.Please help as where to put the js or any other alternate method..

```
<a href="like1?sellerid=<s:property value="id"/>&property_id=<s:property value="p_id"/>"onclick="hide">Like</a>;'
```

Comment: What you have should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpzdpuso/. Check the console for errors.

Comment: <a href="like1?sellerid=<s:property value="id"/>&property_id=<s:property value="p_id"/>"onclick="hide">Like</a>;'

Comment: Please stop editing your question - I have already fixed the code block 3 times now.

Comment: tried that but its not workin..I have provided the codein comments I am passing some values through the link and unable to get the correct position for placing that link

Answer (score 3):

As it has been said this functions is better to be implemented with javascript.
First assign a valid id for the link and follow this:

```
//create a function for the click like:
$('#buttonId').click(hideButton);
```

Afterwards, in your javascript code:

```
function hideButton(){$('#buttonId').css({'visibility':'hidden'})};
```

Remember to import jquery library and import the .js when your code has been displayed if you does not use a .ready function.

Edit: note that in the way previously exposed you will still get the box where the link was, but it is displayed hidden.

Comment: yup this is working but the problem is that once I refresh the page it reappeares

Comment: Then use a control var. Set a var example like: var control=0. Once is clicked set control=1 and put the funcion inside an if that runs the function only if control=0

Comment: Obviously, if you refresh the page all variables are set again into "default" values. So if your application works connected with some other languages as php or sql you have to set there the value control to avoid your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass some values as well as hide element i thing you should use ajax. As you are passing a url to href attribute it will redirect you to that page. A java script function can work better. Call a javascript function on onClick event like

```
<a href="#""onclick="hide()">Like</a>

<script>
function hide(){
// ajax call to send parameter
// hide element
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a class for `anchor` tag , and user ajax post to send the request and then you can just hide the element with `hide()`.

See below example:

```js
$(".like").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.href);
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="like" href="like1?sellerid=-1">Hide me</a>
```